# Strategy for converting / adapting ASCII-art diagrams into tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, ascii-art

Despite my having used (La)TeX quite a bit over the years, I have never produced diagrams using tikz. It's always been LO Draw, or Inkscape, or LO Calc / MS Excel charts, for me.

Now, I am in the process of converting a text+ASCII-art technical report into LaTeX. This presents several challenges, but the one I'm concerned with here is the artwork. This time, unlike on earlier occasions, I'm thinking of using tikz to reproduce the ASCII art.

What kind of art? Essentially, diagrams of 2D projections of 3D entities. There are pixels, there are rectangles, circles, intersecting lines, asterisk-filled areas, some axis illustrations, some textual labels for drawing elements. No super-big diagrams. So, overall, not anything very fancy. Example:

```
 Y
 ^         |   /
 |         |  /
 |         | /
 |    +----|/--+--------+
 |    |####*###|        |
 |    |###/|###|        | 
 |    |##/#|###|        |
 |    +-/--|---+--------+
 |     /   |
 |    /    |
 |   /     |
  ------------------> X
```

My question is: As a tikz newbie, what steps would I need to follow to effect this conversion quickly and with minimum pain? Or - perhaps this is not a good idea, and I would be better served by using a diagram app, then exporting?

Naturally, I would rather not have to follw of the obvious path of first gaining a lot of tikz experience and skills, then "just" redrawing the diagrams with tikz.

Comment: When I hear ASCII art, I think of [pictures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII_art) not diagrams. How would that look like? How 3d are these diagrams? TikZ isn't good with 3d. Your list of items sounds doable with TikZ. If you can describe the relationship between them, you can usually cook something up with TikZ and everything that comes with it.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: They're 2D diagrams. Think of 3D stuff projected onto 2 of its axes. Also, see example.

Comment: they are just lines between points, I think simply re-drawing would be simpler than any conversion, unless you have access to some vector description hat generated the original ascii art

Comment: You don‘t need much from Tikz for this example. Skim through the tutorials in https://tikz.dev to get some of the ideas, focus on \draw[<->], fill, cycle (to close e.g. a polygon) and rect, \node to place a few labels. Less think of drawing and more of „putting several statements along a path“, which only ends with a semicolon. Feel free to post your attempts for focused suggestions.

Comment: Check `ducksay`: Just put ASCII-art in your TeX output :P

Comment: How do you draw circles in ASCII-art? (I'm just curious on how you do it, and at least for your example image here I could imagine an automatic aa2tikz (ACII-art to Ti*k*Z converter) that should at least give some ok-ish results, though monochrome).

Comment: For fun I tried https://pypi.org/project/aafigure/ to convert your diagram into SVG and I got https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xn4QS.png, which you may be able to post-process into something acceptable.

Comment: @Skillmon: I either take a circle from someplace else, or use angled lines (`\`,`|`,`/`,`-`,`_`) for a sort-of-circle-ish shape, increasing the drawing size a bit to improve resolution. It's just intended to get the point across, not to hang in the louvre. Originally these were doxygen comments.

Comment: @Marijn: That's rasterized, so not what I want, but it was still a fun experiment :-)

Comment: @einpoklum actually the output of aafigure is vectorized, the lines are SVG line segments, the axes are arrows and the labels are text. The script has some problems converting the slashes into a continuous line so that ended up as around 10 separate segments, but they are still 'real' lines. If I would implement a hypothetical ascii-to-tikz converter then I would take the same approach I think, maybe with some special-casing for filled shapes and line segment continuity.

Comment: @Marijn: Oh, I see. Ok, then - maybe make that an answer. It's not quite what I want the diagrams to look like, but it's an interesting alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some easy steps for you to keep you going.

Suggestion: comment out many lines, compile and watch the changes.

#### Latex-structure to start Tikz

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
   .... your Tikz code here
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

`standalone` is nice so you don't have to care about sizes during development. You can delete `tikz` from the options and put `\usepackage{tikz}` instead, as ususal. The show starts with the `tikzpicture` environment.

#### pgf-manual, online version

Find it on https://tikz.dev/ , or the pdf version via ctan.

My comments in the code cite some relevant parts from this manual. It's easier tried than read ...

#### Code

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    % ~~~ draw x- and y-axis    # https://tikz.dev/tutorial#sec-2.3 ~~~~~
    %                           # https://tikz.dev/tutorial#sec-2.17
    \draw[<->] (4,0) -- (0,0) -- (0,5);
    
    % ~~~ putting x-y-labels via nodes  # https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#sec-17.2 ~~~~~~
    %                                   # https://tikz.dev/tutorial#sec-2.21
    \node at (4.3,0)    {x};
    \node at (0  , 5.3) {y};
 
    % ~~~ drawing the two lines ~~~~~~~~~~
    %     using cartesian coordinates
    \draw[red]      (2 ,0) -- (2,5);
    \draw[purple]   (.5,0) -- (3,5);
    
    % ~~~ putting those rectangles, closed and open ~~~~~~~~~
    %                                   # https://tikz.dev/tikz-paths#sec-14.1
    \draw[fill=gray]    (1,2) -- (1,4) -- (3,4) -- (3,2) -- cycle;
    \draw                                 (3,4) -- (4,4) -- (4,2) -- (3,2);
 
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

#### Result

[image: result]

#### Some remarks

From a learning perspective it was good to put the red and purple line first, as those statements are, I think, easy to understand.

However, as you can see, they should be drawn later, after the rectangles were shown.

The closed one uses `-- cycle` to close the path, so you can fill it with some color. The second is just a rectangluar structure with its left side missing ... so you can't fill that one, unless you put a `-- cycle` statement.

#### Strategy to go from ASCII to Tikz

I suggest to:

- obtain a basic set of Tikz skill, like the ones above, first
- second, spot such graphical structures in your ASCII-art, like rectangles etc.
- third, pick up and try `Tikz`-ideas you see in the manual or e.g. here, i.e. learn-on-the-fly

And keep in mind, it's still valid:

- TIAMTOWTDI
- there is always more than one way to do it

Comment: Why is tikz an argument to the document class rather than a `\usepackage` ?

Comment: @einpoklum, standalone allows it. I picked it up here and use it as a default since. However, you can also discard the tikz option and load the package. In a nutshell: pure lazyness ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The following is not really to be taken seriously, but I find it amusing enough to post it. (and yes, I find it hilarious that I'm using `pxpic` to define a front end for Ti*k*Z)

We can simply define a converter that automatically converts your fine ASCII-art into inferior Ti*k*Z. YMMV!

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{aa2px.sty}
\ProvidesPackage{aa2px}

\RequirePackage{pxpic}
\RequirePackage{expkv-def}
\RequirePackage{tikz}

\ekvsetdef\aaTpxsetup{aa2px}
\ekvdefinekeys{aa2px}
  {
     store   lines = \aaTpx@color@lines
    ,initial lines = black
    ,store   fills = \aaTpx@color@fills
    ,initial fills = black
    % knowing pxpic uses expkv as well, this will forward all unknown keys:
    ,unknown redirect = pxpic
  }

%\protected\def\aaTpx@letactive#1%
  %{%
    %\catcode`#1=13
    %\begingroup\lccode`\~=`#1\lowercase{\endgroup\let~}= %
  %}
\protected\def\aaTpx@init@ccregime
  {%
    \catcode`\ =12
  }
\protected\def\aaTpx@init
  {%
    \aaTpx@init@ccregime
    \aaTpx@init@symbols
  }
\newcommand\aaTpx@init@symbols{}
\protected\def\aaTpx@new@symbol#1%
  {\expandafter\aaTpx@new@symbol@\csname aaTpx@symbol@#1\endcsname}
\protected\def\aaTpx@new@symbol@#1#2%
  {%
    \newsavebox#1%
    \edef\aaTpx@init@symbols
      {\unexpanded\expandafter{\aaTpx@init@symbols\aaTpx@set@symbol#1{#2}}}%
  }
\protected\def\aaTpx@set@symbol#1#2%
  {%
    \sbox#1%
      {%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[x=.5\pxpicWD,y=.5\pxpicHT]
          \path[use as bounding box] (-1, -1) rectangle (1, 1);
          #2%
        \end{tikzpicture}%
      }%
  }

\aaTpx@new@symbol{ }{}
\aaTpx@new@symbol{|}{\draw[\aaTpx@color@lines](0,1)--(0,-1);}
\aaTpx@new@symbol{-}{\draw[\aaTpx@color@lines](1,0)--(-1,0);}
\aaTpx@new@symbol{/}{\draw[\aaTpx@color@lines](-1,-1)--(1,1);}
\aaTpx@new@symbol{\@backslashchar}{\draw[\aaTpx@color@lines](1,-1)--(-1,1);}
\aaTpx@new@symbol{+}{\draw[\aaTpx@color@lines](0,1)--(0,-1)(1,0)--(-1,0);}
\aaTpx@new@symbol{*}
  {%
    \draw[\aaTpx@color@lines]%
      (0,1)--(0,-1)(1,0)--(-1,0)(-1,-1)--(1,1)(1,-1)--(-1,1);%
  }
\aaTpx@new@symbol{x}{\draw[\aaTpx@color@lines](-1,-1)--(1,1)(-1,-1)--(1,1);}
\aaTpx@new@symbol{\detokenize{#}}{\fill[\aaTpx@color@fills](-1,-1)rectangle(1,1);}
\aaTpx@new@symbol{^}{\fill[\aaTpx@color@lines](0,0)--(-1,-1)--(1,-1)--cycle;}
\aaTpx@new@symbol{>}{\fill[\aaTpx@color@lines](0,0)--(-1,1)--(-1,-1)--cycle;}
\aaTpx@new@symbol{v}{\fill[\aaTpx@color@lines](0,0)--(-1,1)--(1,1)--cycle;}
\aaTpx@new@symbol{<}{\fill[\aaTpx@color@lines](0,0)--(1,1)--(1,-1)--cycle;}

\def\aaTpx@symbol#1{\unhcopy\csname aaTpx@symbol@\detokenize{#1}\endcsname}
\def\aaTpx@hover#1{\rule\z@\pxpicHT\smash{\makebox[\pxpicWD][c]{#1}}}

\pxpicnewmode{aa2px}
  {%
    \@ifundefined{aaTpx@symbol@\detokenize{#1}}%
      \aaTpx@hover
      \aaTpx@symbol
      {#1}%
  }
\newcommand\aaTpx[1][]
  {%
    \begingroup
    \aaTpxsetup{#1}%
    \aaTpx@init
    \aaTpx@collect
  }
\newcommand\aaTpx@collect[1]
  {%
    \pxpic[mode=aa2px,lines=space]{#1}%
    \endgroup
  }
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[border=3.14]{standalone}

\usepackage{aa2px}

\begin{document}
\aaTpx[size=5pt, lines=green]{
 Y
 ^         |   /
 |         |  /
 |         | /
 |    +----|/--+--------+
 |    |####*###|        |
 |    |###/|###|        | 
 |    |##/#|###|        |
 |    +-/--|---+--------+
 |     /   |
 |    /    |
 |   /     |
 +------------------>X
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Inferior tikz banzai :-)

Comment: @einpoklum context sensitive handling of `#`, `+` and `*` would be nice, but unfortunately `pxpic`'s parser doesn't support look-ahead or look-behind operations. I'm somewhat intrigued to write an application in C (mostly because it's been so long since I last wrote a program in C, and this seems like a fun task and I'm not sure whether I want to tackle it with TeX, Python seems boring to me right now).